# Javascript - How to access Arrays of Records

Tags: javascript, arrays, record

I have an array comprising records

```
v = [{stringA, stringB, arr[{stringC,stringD}]
```

When I try to extract the value of stringA and stringB, Javascript returns {Object, Object}

I am trying to use

```
strX = v[4].arr[2].stringC;
```

(this approach works when extracting stringA and stringB, but not when extracting stringC)

Please, does anyone know how this should be done?

Comment: Could you show us some actual code?  Your structure is a bit confused with an extra layer of braces ({}), and I want to know what you really mean

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is badly inaccurate. It's quite difficult to make out what structure you're trying to achieve, but this won't even execute, because of unmatching numbers of `[`, `]` and `{`, `}` in your declaration of `v`.

- You can create an array by specifying comma-separated items within `[`,`]`
- You can create an object by specifying comma-separated `property:value` pairs within `{`, `}`

If you want to be able to write `v[4].arr[2].stringC` then you need a structure that looks like

```
var v = [item0, item1, item2, item3, {
      description: 'this is item 4',
      arr: [ subitem0, subitem1, {
          description: 'this is arr[2]',
          stringC: 'this is the value of string c'
      }
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use:

```
strX = v[0].arr[0].stringC;
```

I see no point for you putting those objects into those arrays. If you remove the array square brackets, the solution you will want to use is:

```
strX = v.arr.stringC;
```